# zip multiple pdfs from url link, how to

Tags: c#, pdf, asp.net-core, zip, memorystream

I have a project that requires pdf files to be zipped up from an URL link and then downloaded and clickable by the end users browser. So far, I was able to zip one pdf file which isn't nearly what I'm looking to for.

I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Below is the code. Any help would be very much appreciated.

> ASP.NET Core

```
        [HttpGet("zipFiles")]
        public IActionResult ZipPDFFiles()
        {
            var fileNames = _repo.GetFileNames();

            foreach (var filesName in fileNames)
            {
                var urlLink = "https://example.com/folder/" + $"{filesName.PdfFileName}";

                var net = new System.Net.WebClient();
                var data = net.DownloadData(urlLink);

                var file = $"{filesName.PdfFileName}";

                var contentType = "application/zip";

                string zippedFolderName = "Archive.zip";

                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var archive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
                    {
                        var zipArchiveEntry = archive.CreateEntry($"{file}", System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel.Fastest);
                        using (var zipStream = zipArchiveEntry.Open()) zipStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    }
                    return File(ms.ToArray(), contentType, $"{zippedFolderName}");
                }

            }
            return NotFound();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Some improvements:

- used HttpClient
- files uploaded simultaneously

```cs
        var fileUrls = new[]
        {
            new Uri("https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/implement-resilient-applications/media/image3.5.png"),
            new Uri("https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/implement-resilient-applications/media/image4.png"),
            new Uri("https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/implement-resilient-applications/media/image6.png")
        };

        var downloadResults = fileUrls
            .Select(uri => (uri: uri, response: HttpClientFactory.Create().SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri))))
            .ToArray();

        await Task.WhenAll(downloadResults.Select(v => v.response));

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var archive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
            {
                foreach (var download in downloadResults)
                {
                    var entry = archive.CreateEntry(download.uri.Segments.Last(), CompressionLevel.Fastest);

                    using (var zipStream = entry.Open())
                    {
                        var data = await download.response.Result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

                        zipStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    }
                }
            }

            return File(ms.ToArray(), contentType, $"{zippedFolderName}");
        }
```

Comment: thank you for the comment. The files reference are stored in a db. The actual files are in the URL link. How can I loop through the link and add zip entries per file?

Comment: Thank you again for the update. What if I wanted to zip files from an URL link? For example if the link was: `var urlLink = "https://example.com/folder/" + $"{filesName.PdfFileName}";`? I have the reference from my db, and I just iterate thru the url's ending. Just like the above example. From your example, you have an array of links which works, but isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Chris H. - i give you rod, please catch fish by yourself :)

Comment: the rod is to short. lol. I'll have to ask the question again to get help. Thank you again for your help.